# Accessing html table rows in python django

Tags: django

Hi I am very new to both django and python... I have a html table with person information in each row...How do i get a particular row entry/id of the one i need to edit/delete to accordingly update/delete the row in database??

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: What does it even mean, to talk about 'accessing html table rows'? An HTML table is not a data source.

Answer (score 0):

You use a [formset](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) for that.

Comment: does formset work like datagrid/gridview... I get rseultset by querying the database table... And i wish to display it in some grid like view where i can update or delete any particular row.... I think using normal html table i cant get the particular row details... I wish to use something like datagrid/gridview...